# Similarity between coordinates in R

Tags: r, statistics, coordinates, statistical-test

I would like to know if in R, there is a way to see the similarity between two dataframes with coordinates. I have two groups of dates A and B, with the coordinates of sightings of two different species in each one, so, A has longitude and latitude, and B also. I would like to know if the coordinates of these two species are similar, i mean, if A and B are statistically similar.

I've thought about using Soresen's index or ratio of variances with normalcy test, but I don't think it will work with coordinates.

Thank you very much!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. If you are just seeking general advice about what to use rather than how to do it, maybe first get statistical advice at [stats.se]. Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions, rather than data analysis advice.

Comment: You would be looking for `r home range analysis`  or `r Soresen index species` a search (google) that will lead you to r packages that help you do this analysis.